# How to make efficient cicular Linked List?

Tags: c, circular-list

I'm studing Circular Linked List. Below is my code.

```
typedef struct circle {

    int data;
    struct circle* next;
} Node;

typedef struct circle {

    int number;
    Node *Header;
} Circular_List;

void add(Circular_List* circle, int number, int data) {

    if (number <0 && number > circle->number)
    {
        printf("number is wrong. \n");
    }
    else
    {


        if (number == 0 && circle->number != 0)
        {

            Node* pre = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            Node* add_data = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            Node* tempt = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            pre = circle->Header;


            while (pre->next != circle->Header )
            {
                pre = pre->next;
            }

            circle->number++;
            tempt = circle->Header;
            circle->Header = add_data;
            pre->next = add_data;
            add_data->next = tempt;
            add_data->data = data;
        }
        else if (number == 0 && circle->number == 0)
        {
            Node* add_data = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            circle->Header = add_data;
            add_data->data = data;
            add_data->next = add_data;
            circle->number++;
        }
        else
        {

            Node* pre = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            Node* add_data = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            pre = circle->Header;
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                pre = pre->next;
            }
            add_data->data = data;
            add_data->next = pre->next;
            pre->next = add_data;
            circle->number++;
        }

    }
}
```

It runs well. But I think my code is not efficient.

Because when I add a just one new Node, I allocate 3 NODE memory and do not free any of them.

It seems like waste memory.

How can I adjust my code? or

Is it a right way to make a  cicular Linked List?

Comment: You need one new node, and stick it to its right and left neighbors (changing the right link on left one, left link on right one, to new node, and fix new node left / right)

Comment: Check this out it may help. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-singly-linked-list-insertion/